# Error TS1005 on intermediator Agent UI sample

Tags: c#, node.js, typescript, botframework

I cloned this repo https://github.com/billba/agent on GitHub for Agent UI but I got error when I run the npm run build command.

what could have been the issue?

I have updated my typescript version and also downgraded it but same issues

node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(24,36): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(45,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(59,45): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(69,42): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(79,49): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(103,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(110,32): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(119,45): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(132,49): error TS1005: ',' expected.
node_modules/@types/whatwg-streams/index.d.ts(136,43): error TS1005: ',' expected.